# Add default class on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on my app and had this jQuery code that adds `active` class on current location which is working just fine.

Now my problem is that I need to know how to set a default or I should say place the `active` class on `Home` link whenever there is no link selected or the URL is `http://localhost:3000/`

```
var url = window.location.href;

var link = window.location.hash
$('a.ks-nav.active-menu').removeClass('active'); 

$('a.ks-nav[data-id="' + link.replace('#', '') + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Here are my links:

```
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="home" href="/#home">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="about" href="/#about">About</a>
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="contact" href="/#contact">Contact</a>
```

How can I set a jQuery default code that adds the `active` class on `Home` whenever there are no setup `active` class on any of the available menu? This needs a deeper checking and make sure there are no other element that has the class cause basically when they click on a different menu the `Home` link must remove the `active` class and will go to that link URL / click menu.

Please help!

Comment: if your page reload while clicking `anchor tag` and you have added some class using jquery automatic remove because you page refresh so you need to manage using local store something like that.

Comment: @jishansiddique please provide answer below thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change in your HTML:

```
<a class="active nav-link ks-nav" data-id="home" href="/#home">Home</a>
```

Comment: I think this is not a good answer. If I add that by default it will messed up with other codes.

Comment: @JoanBuan By default set Home page as active. I don't think this messed up anything. Because your js code initially remove any active class from menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` property of the jQuery object like this:

```js
var url = window.location.href;

var link = window.location.hash

var linkTag = $('a.ks-nav[data-id="' + link.replace('#', '') + '"]');

if (linkTag.length) {
  linkTag.addClass('active');
} else {
  $('.ks-nav[data-id="home"]').addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.ks-nav.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="home" href="/#home">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="about" href="/#about">About</a>
<a class="nav-link ks-nav" data-id="contact" href="/#contact">Contact</a>
```

Comment: What does lenght do it the code? Its not clear to me can you explain in laymans term?

Comment: `$('.ks-nav.active')` looks for any element that has `.ks-nav` and `.active` classes, and length returns the number of such elements. So, if that length is greater than 0, it means there is at least one element that has `.active` class. If not, it means there is no active nav, so we're highlighting "home" nav.

Comment: Do i need to add `$('a.ks-nav.active-menu').removeClass('active'); 

$('a.ks-nav[data-id="' + link.replace('#', '') + '"]').addClass('active'); ` It seems there is a bit of delay when clicking on the home link

Comment: I tried to put your code at the very bottom and there is that delay and highlight the about when home is click.

Comment: The error is not reproducible in that link unfortunately.

Comment: After clicking the about or contact it will highlight and put `active` class first on `home` before finally adding it to the click or urled item.

Comment: its ok however whenever there is no selected data-id like the URL is `https://localhost:3000` the `HOME` is not selected.

Comment: Yes. Just right now the `https://localhost:3000` is the URL and `home` is not selected or doesnt have the `active` class on it.

Comment: If you use the exact same code, I'm pretty confident that it should work. there might be some code that's different.